# Exporting Recordset to an HTML Table (Object Doesn't Support This Property or Method)

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to figure out as to why I would be getting an error "Object Doesn't Support This Property or Method" As far as I am aware, I seem to be doing everything by the book.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```
function test() {
    try {
        alert("running function test...")
        var cn      = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection")
        var sql     = "SELECT * FROM tbl_rssims"
        var db      = "G:\\AS\\Asf\\ASF\\RSSIMS\\db\\rssims.mdb"
        cn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = " + db + "")

        rs = cn.Execute(sql);

                var trs = [ ];
                while ( ! rs.EOF )
                {
                    var tr = [ ];
                    for ( var td = 1; td <= 2; ++td )
                    {
                        if ( ! rs.EOF ) 
                        {
                            var flds = [ ];
                            for ( var f = 0; f < rs.fields.length; ++f )
                            {
                               flds.push( rs.fields(f).value );
                            }
                            trs.MoveNext();
                            tr.push( flds.join("<br/>") );

                        } else {
                            tr.push( "&nbsp;" );
                        }
                    }
                    trs.push( "<td>" + tr.join("</td><td>") + "</td>\n" );
                }

        rs.close
        cn.close

        var html = '<!DOCTYPE html>\n'
                         + "<html><body" +
             + '<table style="border: none; table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; text-align: left;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">\n'
                         + "<tr>" + trs.join("</tr><tr>") + "</tr>"
                         + '</table></body></html>';
        window.open('','').document.write(html)

    }//end of try

    catch(e) {

        alert(e.description)

    }

}//end of function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out the problem with the object was trs.movenext() where it should have been rs.Movenext(), there was nothing wrong with the actual writting of the HTML.

Thanks for everyones help though.

Answer (score 2):

the question is very hard to work with because you do not tell us what line is throwing the error... **however** it looks like you are trying to call a function when you likely want to access the array here:

```
flds.push( rs.fields(f).value );
```

change this to

```
flds.push( rs.fields[f].value );
```

and you should be ok.

## edit

now we can deal with the window.open method...

```
var win = window.open("","");
win.onload = function() {
    win.document.documentElement.innerHTML = html;
};
```

You can try this and see if it helps. But again, knowing where the actual error is would be much more helpful.

Comment: Changed it, but produced the same result, can't seem to figure this out. =\

Comment: It would be a lot more helpful for you to tell us what line is actually throwing the error @JasonKelly - however my next suspect is the window.open().document.write chain.... I don't think you can chain it like this.